# Postgresql database index scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I've the following query, which takes around 25ms on my db.

https://explain.depesz.com/s/Enar

In another analyzer I'm spotting 2 bad estimates for Merge join and Index scan, how can I instruct db to estimate more "correct"?

Comment: Start by running `VACUUM ANALYZE;` on the tables. BTW: 25 ms is not a measure for a benchmark. (maybe except when this is a real-world query)

Comment: Show the query please.